# Parsing out "site.com" from a passed variable in PHP?

Tags: php, parse-url

I'm passing through a variety of URLs in a global variable called target_passthrough, so the URL of a page might look like:
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?target_passthrough=example.com

Or something like that.  Formats for that variable may be a variety of things such as (minus quotes):

1. "www.example.com"
2. ".example.com"
3. "example.com"
4. "http://www.example.com"
5. ".example.com/subdir/"
6. ".example.com/subdir/page.php"
7. "example.com/subdir/page.php"

Please note how some of those have periods as the first character such as 2,5, and 6.

Now, what I am trying to do is pull out just "example.com" from any of those possible scenarios with PHP and store it to a variable to echo out later.  I tried parse_url but it gives me the "www" when that is present, which I do not want.  In instances where the url is just "example.com" it returns a null value.

I don't really know how to do regex matching or if that is even what I need so any guidance would be appreciated--not really that advanced at php.

Comment: See if you can make use of preg_match.

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to do much of the work for you and then simply strip off the `www` or leading dot if it is present.

An alternative strategy of taking the last two "words" won't always work because there are domains like `www.example.co.uk`. Using this strategy would give you `co.uk` instead of `example.co.uk`. There is no simple rule for determining which parts are the domain or the sub-domain.

Comment: If you really really really want to just get the last two, just do a split on the '.', but I would have to agree with OP.

Answer (score 0):

parse_url() outputs an array the different parts of the URL. You are getting null values because you are only referencing the first item in the array. [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
 Array (
        [scheme] => http
        [host] => hostname
        [user] => username
        [pass] => password
        [path] => /path
        [query] => arg=value
        [fragment] => anchor 
         )
```